# How to set ciphers in ssl python socket

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I want to create my own list of ciphersuites using the cipher strings. The following code works if I put only one string in the `set_ciphers` function. But I want a customized list of ciphers. There is other format like: `ALL:!COMPLEMENTOFDEFAULT:!eNULL` but this does not do the purpose I need. I have a customized list of different ciphers that I can not combine using the second format.

```
import socket, ssl
import pprint

context = ssl.create_default_context()

cipher = ['DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA', 'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA', 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256']
context.set_ciphers(cipher)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

domain = 'google.com'

sslSocket = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname = domain)

sslSocket.connect((domain, 443))
sslSocket.close()
print('closed')
```

The function `set_ciphers` can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.set_ciphers).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could include more than one cipher simple by separating the ciphers with `:` and send all the ciphers as one string.

```
cipher = 'DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256'
context.set_ciphers(cipher)
```

This way, the client offers all the ciphers. You can make sure from this by calling `context.get_ciphers()` and you will see only the ciphers you inserted using `set_cipher`.

Comment: hi, is the set_cipher should be called from client side or mandatory in both sides client and server

Answer (score 3):

Even if ***ssl.SSLContext.get_ciphers*** returns the ciphers in a friendly format (a list of dictionaries), the other way around, things don't work quite the same.

According to [[Python.Docs]: ssl - SSLContext.set_ciphers(ciphers)](https://docs.python.org/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.set_ciphers):

> Set the available ciphers for sockets created with this context. It should be a string in the [OpenSSL cipher list format](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ciphers.html).

Following [[OpenSSL]: CIPHER LIST FORMAT](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-ciphers.html#CIPHER-LIST-FORMAT) (**emphasis** is mine):

> The cipher list consists of **one or more *cipher strings* separated by colons**. Commas or spaces are also acceptable separators but colons are normally used.

Therefore, strings like *"DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256"* should be used.
Translated to (your) code:

```py
ciphers = ["DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA", "DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA", "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256"]
ciphers_str = ":".join(ciphers)  # "DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256"
context.set_ciphers(ciphers_str)
```